# Щодо інших мов (окрім української й англійської) у запитаннях і відповідях

Tags: discussion, languages

Припустімо, я знаю, що автор запитання найкраще володіє французькою. Якщо я відповім йому **лише** французькою, то це, звісно, неправильно — це буде неповага до всіх інших учасників. Але чи заборонено **продублювати** мою відповідь французькою?

Тобто [давно відомо](/q/4), що дозволені мови — українська й англійська. Але виникає питання, як саме це інтерпретувати:

- (а) чи це означає, що має бути наявний текст запитання/відповіді українською/англійською (але дублювати іншими мовами не заборонено);
- (б) чи це означає, що жодного слова іншими мовами не може бути в запитанні/відповіді (окрім, звісно, явно наведених цитат/оригіналів/тощо)?

Питання виникло [тут](/a/5825). Мій особистий підхід був «а» (але я підкорюся поглядам більшості).

<sub>Підпитання. Я особисто не виділяю російську (я вважаю, що не слід ставитися до неї краще чи гірше, ніж до інших мов). Але якщо учасник вважає, що для неї слід ввести якісь окремі правила, то про це теж можна/варто написати у відповіді.</sub>

Comment: Проблема полягає в тім, що ми усі чудово усвідомлюємо, що йдеться зовсім не про «припустімо, французьку» мову. У нас наразі не було запитань, написаних «припустімо, французькою». Так само як китайською чи тайською (би-м відповів).

Comment: @bytebuster, я якраз кажу про всі мови. І китайською чи тайською, якщо консенсус не схилиться до іншої відповіді, Ви теж, виходить, продублювати відповідь не зможете. (А якщо хочете впровадити для російської якісь особливі правила, наприклад, окремо заборонити — то про це теж ішлося в кінці питання — хоча, по-моєму, це було б неправильно.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ой. Перепрошую. Дописуючи запитання, я вже сам знайшов [відповідь](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/109048):

> Remove non-English content.

У нашому випадку це, відповідно, трансформується у «приберіть контент, окрім того, що англійською й українською».

Хоча це не є якимось правилом, а радше є рішенням окремої спільноти (Stack Overflow), і ми теоретично могли б ухвалити інше рішення — але це все-таки прецедент (і щось мені підказує, що іншого рішення в нас не буде; і хоч я особисто іншої думки, але доведеться змиртися).

Comment: Відповідно, [переклав і ту відповідь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/posts/5825/revisions).